# CodeIgniter - custom URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Couldn't find solutions for my question. Who uses CodeIgniter knows that all URL in this framework are constructed as:

`site.com/controller/method/parameter...`

Is there a way fro changing that into some other pattern as for excample:

`site.com/controller-method-parameter.html`

So in general is there a way to simple change `/` for any other such char as `-` and having those urls generated atomaticly using ie. url helper?

Comment: im not sure what you are looking for, but in codeigniter you have route concept - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: You probably need to try .htaccess rewrite

Comment: All cool @Janith with routes, i'm getting the concept there. What i want to achieve is Your normal approach would be in controller like:
`$this->load->helper('url');
site_url('applicationform/apply');`
And You would get url like: `site.com/controller/method` what i'm aiming for is still use `site_url('applicationform/apply')` but at the frontend having for excample `site.com/applicationform-appy`. Just replace `/` with `-` and still be able to use those helpers

Comment: you are trying to do some things which is not given in the user guide i think you have to use other options like htaccess is the only options

Comment: There is no configuration for urls "join" char? .htaccess isn't the way i would like to use in this case because of loss of some functionality of framework.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that.
use the Routes class, for example you have a controller named 'stories' and a method called 'story' that takes a parametre 'story id' and display the appropriate story,
so in your routes config file put

```
$route['story-(:num)'] = 'stories/story/$1';
```

that's it :)

for more information take a look here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html